# Term for a correspondence of two point sets regarding their ordering in each dimension

Tags: cg.comp-geom, terminology, metric-spaces

Let there be two sets of points $S$ and $S'$ in $R^d$. $|S| = |S'|$, and for each point $s_i$ in $S$ it exists exactly one corresponding point $s'_i$ in $S'$, such that the ordering of $S$ equals the ordering of $S'$ with respect to any axis of $R^d$.

Is there any term that describes this relationship or 'morphism' between $S$ and $S'$?

E.g. in $R^2$, if $x_{s_i} < x_{s_j}$ then $x_{s'_i} < x_{s'_j}$, or if $y_{s_i} \ge y_{s_j}$ then $y_{s'_i} \ge y_{s'_j}$, etc.

Comment: Maybe a general term would be 'order isomorphic'? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_isomorphism) -- but there might be something more specific?

Comment: A _pointwise order-preserving function_ or _pointwise monotone function_.

Comment: I think that simply _monotone_ suffices in this case, because the function maps $S\to S'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associate with $S$ and $S'$ the posets $P = (\leq, S)$ and $P' = (\leq, S')$, where $\leq$ is the [dominance order](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dominance.html) in $\mathbb{R}^d$. The function you describe is an [isomorphism](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IsomorphicPosets.html) between $P$ and $P'$.